# TikZ: lineto to a just created node

Tags: tikz-pgf, node-connections

Often, when drawing diagrams with TikZ, I’d like link nodes by edges just as I draw them. But when doing it the naive way, e.g.

```
\draw (0,0) node {A} -- (1,0) node {B};
```

the line intersects with the node labels. I get the desired result by drawing the edge after the nodes:

```
\path (0,0) node (A) {A} (1,0) node (B) {B};
\draw (A) -- (B);
```

But for that, I have to hand out names to the nodes. Is it possible to obtain that result in one `\draw` command, without using names? Preferably a solution less involved than the chain library.

Comment: Using `\draw (0,0) node [fill=white] {A} -- (1,0) node [fill=white] {B};` removes the intersection problem, but I don't know if the output is exactly the same as your second example.

Comment: I’d consider that a work-around, and I am looking for a solution that gives the same result – but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `append after command` key which works inside a path command.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw node (a) {A} node[append after command={(a)--(b)}] (b) at (1,0) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And please post full MWEs as I have provided in the answer so that anybody can copy-paste your code and try out a possible solution

Comment: Interesting, but still requires naming the nodes. Are there maybe explicit node names available for “current” and “previous” nodes?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner There are but they are more laborous than naming your nodes such as `\tikzlastnode`etc. What is your context?

Comment: With context, you mean use case? It is still developing, but a long chain of manually placed nodes is a close approximation.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner Then use the `join` styles. See the manual for the `chains` library.